# Find files created 30 minutes before AND after a given file - UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, command, debian, command-line-interface

I am trying to figure out the command to display all files created 30 minutes (as an example) before and after another file was created. So far I managed to find files newer than that file
but I cannot work out how to look for both before and after given time.

A command I have used:
find -type f -newer file.txt -cmin -30

This works fine but only does half of what I am trying to do.
Also, I need to modify that to search for setuid files only, which I THINK I can do by adding the -perm -4000 in that command.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `cmin` does *not* look at creation time.  The creation time of a file is not recorded in any common filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to find file creation time. 
You can try by modification time (this will get all files last-modified between 5th and 8th)

```
find . -type f -newermt 2012-10-05 ! -newermt 2012-10-08
```

(or access time replace `newermt` with `newerat`)

`newerXY` is flag to compare timestamps of current file with reference (see man find for more info).

According to `man find` (on my debian) there are 4 flags (aside from `t` to interpret directly as time)

```
a   The access time of the file reference
B   The birth time of the file reference
c   The inode status change time of reference
m   The modification time of the file reference
```

You can also try with `'B'` birth time but it does not work for me, gives me error. I don't know why it is included in the man page

compare to another file

```
find / -newer file
find / ! -newer file
```

You can create temp file (one with modification time 30 min before the target file, another 30 mins after)

```
touch -d `stat -c %y test.txt` - 30 temp/before_temp
touch -d `stat -c %y test.txt` + 30 temp/after_temp

find / -newer temp/before_temp ! -newer temp/after_temp
```

`touch -d` takes a date option, so if you add and subtract correctly, this should work.